# Understanding the process for generating Random Forest model in caret

Tags: machine-learning, r, random-forest, cross-validation, model-evaluations

This is not so much a problem, as it is me making sure I understand what's happening with my Random Forest algorithm.

Below, I've set a few parameters. Am I right in thinking that this is the stages:

1. Model is being run 10 times due to 10 Fold Cross Validation, whereby data is being split into 10 folds (9 used for training, 1 for validation - repeated k times, each time with a different group used for validation).
2. For each model, 500 individual decision trees (`ntree`) are being generated to create the Random Forest.
3. Because `tuneLength` is 5, steps 1 and 2 are repeated 5 times - each time with `mtry` being set to a different number.

Also, I ran this on my **training data**.

Is it normal practice to next pass the separate **test data** into the model to check how well it's able to predict the target variable. Then if satisfied with the outcome, re-create the model with all of the data?

I could really use some clarification here, as I think I may be getting this all wrong. The results of the below model tell me what the optimal `mtry` is (i.e. 2). So I'm unsure if I should then be creating an entirely new model, removing the `trControl` parameter, and manually adding in `mtry` as 2 if possible.

```
set.seed(1)
rf_test <- train(mortality ~., 
                 data = rf_train, 
                 method = "rf", 
                 ntree = 500,
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "CV", number = 10),
                 tuneLength = 5)
print(rf_test)
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct (including the next steps).

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks. So because steps 1 and 2 are repeated 5 times, is it correct to say that 25,000 decision trees are generated in total for this one algorithm? (500 * 10 * 5). Also, looking at documentation, I don't think there is a way to actually set `mtry` manually

Comment: Yes, 25K trees; and there are of course various ways to set `mtry` manually